# Why didn't the children of the Rikudo Sennin inherit his surname?

Tags: naruto

As revealed in Chapter 646, the surname from Rikudo Sennin (Sage of the Six Paths) is "Oosutsuki."

Why do his two sons have different surnames (Uchiha and Senju), instead of inheriting their father's surname?

Comment: I think it is because the two sons couldn't get along. And then they didn't want to share the same surname, so they both changed. This is just a guess though.

Comment: I don't think his sons were named Uchiha and Senjuu. The Uchiha and Senjuu are *descendants* from his sons. But I may be wrong

Comment: This question *might be* opinion-based or speculations for now.

Comment: My speculation is on the same line as JNat, I don't remember them being called by names anywhere but only that they were the starting point of two clans, Also I do believe its normal place for the surname to change over generations say when one clan mingles with another and the subsequent generation might even adopt the mother's/father's clan surname or have their own new name for clan as a surname to show the uniqueness... best example that I know where surname does not have to follow from the ancestor is with a Harry Potter reference Marvolo Gaunt -> Salzar Slytherin -> Tom Marvolo *Riddle*

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [the *Naruto* Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_of_the_Six_Paths):

> His bloodline was divided into the descendants of his two children, which would eventually form the Senju clan — and through distant relations the Uzumaki clan — and the Uchiha clan.